# Developing apps in VS2010 for Windows Phone (Mango): How?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I want to try my hands at developing apps for Windows Phone (Mango 7.5) this weekend.

I have Visual Studio 2010, a Samsung Omnia S7530 (Windows Mango Phone 7.5) and Internet facility.

What are the steps required to do so? What updates/security paches are required. (I do not want and have means to upgrade VS2010 to VS2012 or something)?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Mango-Jump-Start/Mango-Jump-Start-01-Building-Windows-Phone-Apps-with-Visual-Studio-2010

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download the windows phone sdk [here](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk). For Windows Phone Mango you need version 7.1
You need sp1 for visual studio 2010 if you don't have it yet

Also don't forget to download the 7.1.1 update.

**Other requirements:**

- Windows® Vista® (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 – all editions except Starter Edition
- Windows 7 (x86 and x64) – all editions except Starter Edition
- Installation requires 4 GB of free disk space on the system drive.
- 3 GB RAM
- Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 or above capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver